# Go to in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, goto

Python 3 have no GOTO or something like this. But I have some algoritm, that need GOTO type functionality.
May be someone can suggest way out?

Main menu

1-New Game
2-Options
3-Exit

User actions - enter to main menu - enter to options menu - enter to main menu AGAIN and so on. So in code I don't know how turn back and teleport to upper code with main menu.

Comment: That algorithm doesn't need goto, or anything remotely like it. Simple recursion would work if Python implemementations had tail call optimization (they don't). Lacking that, a bunch of functions and a loop tying them together and handling the switching is sufficient and still pretty simple.

Comment: @delnan: yes, [tail call elimination can be implemented in Python by trampolining](http://ideone.com/I3T3wq) but continuation-passing style might not be easy to understand for a beginner.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm not talking about doing full trampolining. I'm not even sure I can understand CPS programs myself. Simple token return values used to select the next function to invoke (as in your example, with `x` not coming from stdin but from `actions[x]()`) works just fine. The screen's execution itself does not have to be involved at all. And the "trampoline" loop doesn't even need a stack (or similar state) depending on how menus are used.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary: 'user choice' -> 'corresponding action' e.g.:

```
import sys

def foo():
    print('foo')

actions = {'1': foo, '2': sys.exit}

def read_choice(choices, prompt):
    c = None
    while c not in choices:
        c = input(prompt)
    return c

while True:
    # get user input
    x = read_choice(actions, 'Input 1 to do foo or 2 to exit')
    actions[x]() # act on it
```

See [complete example](http://ideone.com/I3T3wq) that also shows how to create menu dynamically from a configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, trying to understand. :)