# Recursion to Iteration? Max recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have a program that I want to indefinitely run that displays a random 5 long alphanumeric string with time generated. I have a condition that checks the string to display that a substring was included in the generation. The problem is that I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I have the following:

```
import random,datetime
def gen():
    global rand
    rand=''.join(random.choice('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') for i in range(5))
    return rand

def main(num):
    print datetime.datetime.now(),'::',num
    if 'xxx' in num:
        print 'Generated string contains xxx! Continuing...'
        main(gen())
    else:
        print datetime.datetime.now(),'::', num
        'xxx not in string.'
        main(gen())

main(gen())
```

How can I go about converting this or rectifying this issue? Thank you

Comment: Change the recursion to iteration.  It makes no sense for this to be recursive, and evidently Python isn't smart enough to handle this as tail recursion.

Comment: @TomKarzes - Python doesn't do TCO, because [GvR felt that a full stack trace was more important](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html).

Comment: @Tom: It does make *sense*, it's just an unusual and inappropriate style.

Comment: @TomKarzes: you could add a TCO decorator if you'd like but the code should be rewritten in a more idiomatic way instead: `for num in iter(gen, None): print("{now}...`

Comment: unrelated: remove `global rand`: it does nothing useful here. And globals should be avoided in general.

Comment: you could also [use a trampoline, to avoid the recursion limit (continuation-passing style)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161988/user-input-in-python#comment33663979_22161988)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: there is [TCO decorator if you need it](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#tail-call-optimization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use an infinite loop, and call `gen()` from within the loop rather than passing it as an argument to `main`:

```
def main():
    while 1:
        num = gen()
        print datetime.datetime.now(),'::',num
        if 'xxx' in num:
            print 'Generated string contains xxx! Continuing...'
        else:
            print datetime.datetime.now(),'::', num
            'xxx not in string.'

main()
```